# Mysql Update and sorting list

Tags: mysql

Initially table 'my_product'

```
pr_id   sort_pr   group_pr
 321      -1         2
 422      -2         2
 621      -3         2
 921      -4         2
 753      -5         2
 713      -6         2
 573      -7         2
 570      -8         2
 521      -9         2
 901      -1         3
```

For example, user while working on website to remove some products from list,

```
pr_id   sort_pr   group_pr
 321      -1         2
 753      -5         2
 573      -7         2
 521      -9         2
 901      -1         3
```

I would like to sort column 'sort_pr' and get result, as below:

```
pr_id   sort_pr   group_pr
 321      -1         2
 753      -2         2
 573      -3         2
 521      -4         2
 901      -1         3
```

This is my request:

```
UPDATE `my_product` SET time_column=sort_pr, sort_pr='-1' WHERE group_pr='2' 
UPDATE `my_product` SET sort_pr=(SELECT MIN(sort_pr))-1, time_column='0' WHERE group_pr='2' ORDER BY time_column DESC
```

But it does not work...

Is it possible to sort a list and save the order in a single update?

Comment: Why do you want to sort it? Instead just sort it when you're actually displaying it somewhere by making a `SELECT` statement. That would be easier tbh.

Comment: Dipen Shah, problem is that 'sort_pr' is key in local database

Comment: Key or not key, you can still sort it.

Answer (score 0):

I have written query for you. I hope it will resolve your problem :

```
SELECT 
    pr_id, cnt
FROM
    (SELECT 
        pr_id,
            @prevgrouppr,
            CASE
                WHEN group_pr != @prevgrouppr THEN @rownum:=- 1
                ELSE @rownum:=@rownum - 1
            END AS cnt,
            @prevgrouppr:=group_pr
    FROM
        my_product
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevgrouppr:=0) r) AS t
```

**For Update**

```
UPDATE my_product
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        pr_id,
            @prevgrouppr,
            CASE
                WHEN group_pr != @prevgrouppr THEN @rownum:=-1 ELSE @rownum:=@rownum - 1
            END AS cnt,
            @prevgrouppr:=group_pr
    FROM
        my_product
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevgrouppr:=0) r) AS t ON t.pr_id = my_product.pr_id 
SET 
    my_product.sort_pr = t.cnt
;
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec48ff/1/0)